# Using the "wait/loading" cursor as a background image

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm using Chrome and I really like their 'cursor: wait' style. I doubt this is possible but would it be possible to use as a background-image in a div, not on hover or where my mouse is? Or Is my only option to find the file and place it locally? The file seems like its a different file format so that would kinda complicates things.

Comment: just googled the image with keyword "cursor wait "

Comment: I did end up finding it by looking for windows 7 busy cursor, was hoping to be able to get my hands on the original but found a pretty decent one in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's using the OS animation (I get a Windows-looking spinner)

I dont know if its easily extracted from somewhere, but you can find something similar you can use however you wish from http://preloaders.net/

Comment: Great page for preloaders.

Comment: Thanks found some interesting ones

Answer (score 1):

That's not chrome's cursor. It depends how are your mouse cursors set in windows. `cursor: wait` is simply telling browser which cursor should be showed when hovering over that element. Mine looks like this:

[image: Mine looks like this]

To use similar thing for background you would need a picture (can be a gif or you can animate it with CSS) and simple css.

```
.cursor-wait:hover {
    background-image: url("image.png");
}
```